# C - Array content exchange

Tags: c, arrays, string, matrix

I'm actually trying, with a bi-dimensionnal array of string ( It could bi tri-dimensionnal in fact ), to exchange two "cells" of the array.

Before, i used memcpy but when comes long string, comes long execution time so I thought it was possible to simply exchange the pointers of the array but I don't know how to do :(

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fonction(unsigned char*** tab);

int main()
{
    unsigned char*** tab;
    tab = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char**) * 3);
    if (tab == NULL)
        exit(0);

    for (int line = 0; line < 3; line++)
        tab[line] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*) * 3);

    for (int line = 0; line < 3; line++)
        for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
            tab[line][column] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 5);


    for (int line = 0; line < 3; line++)
        for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
            for (int cell = 0;cell < 5;cell++)
                tab[line][column][cell] = line * 3 * 5 + column * 5 + cell;



    for (int i = 0;i < 32;i++)
        fonction(tab);

    for (int line = 0; line < 3; line++)
        for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
            free(tab[line][column]);

    for (int line = 0; line < 3; line++)
        free(tab[line]);

    free(tab);

    return 0;
}

void fonction(unsigned char*** tab)
{
    unsigned char temp[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    int alea = 0;
    int alea2 = 0;
    int alea3 = 0;
    int alea4 = 0;

    srand(58);

    for (int line = 0; line < 3; line++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
        {
            alea = rand() % 3;
            alea2 = rand() % 3;
            alea3 = rand() % 3;
            alea4 = rand() % 3;

            *temp = tab[alea][alea2];
            tab[alea][alea2] = tab[alea3][alea4];
            tab[alea3][alea4] = *temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Errors come when freeing tab and this is expectable because *fonction* does any old thing :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is no 2D/bi-dimensional (or any other X-dimensional) array iny your code, nor anything which can point to one.A pointer is not an array. And being a 3-star (`***`) C-programmer is not a compliment. It is a signal of bad interface design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using

```
   unsigned char temp[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Just use

```
    char* temp;
```

And do swapping as

```
        temp = tab[alea][alea2];
        tab[alea][alea2] = tab[alea3][alea4];
        tab[alea3][alea4] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really get what you were trying to do with your code, but here's a working example of moving string pointers around:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STR_NUM 3

int main(void)
{ 
    char * str1[STR_NUM] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    char * str2[STR_NUM];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < STR_NUM; ++i)
        puts(str1[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < STR_NUM; ++i)
        str2[i] = str1[i];

    for (i = 0; i < STR_NUM; ++i)
        puts(str2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```